is there any way to remove tooltip from toggle button in flowbite-react sidebar component?
When the sidebar is closed and you hover over any item of sidebar, it shows a tooltip.
I don't want that tooltip on toggle button because there it does not make sense.
Is there any way that I can hide this tooltip from toggle button only. It should for other items.
import React from "react";
import { Sidebar, Flowbite, Button } from "flowbite-react";
import {
  HiChartBar,
  HiMailOpen,
  HiDatabase,
  HiPencilAlt,
  HiLink,
  HiShoppingCart,
  HiOutlineViewGrid,
} from "react-icons/hi";

const RightSidebar = () => {
  const customTheme = {
    sidebar: {
      root: {
        base: "list-none",
        inner: "h-full overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden px-3 py-4 bg-black",
      },
      collapse: {
        button:
          "group flex w-full items-center rounded-lg p-2 text-base font-normal text-slate-200       transition duration-75 hover:bg-zinc-600",
        icon: {
          base: "h-6 w-6 text-slate-200 transition duration-75",
          open: {
            off: "",
            on: "",
          },
        },
      },
      item: {
        base: "flex items-center justify-center transition-all duration-300 rounded-lg p-2 text-base font-normal text-slate-200 hover:bg-zinc-600 active:bg-zinc-700",
        content: {
          base: "flex-1 whitespace-nowrap px-3",
        },
        icon: {
          base: "h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0",
        },
      },
    },
  };
  return (
    <Flowbite theme={{ theme: customTheme }}>
      <Sidebar collapsed aria-label="Default sidebar example">
        <Sidebar.Collapse icon={HiOutlineViewGrid}>
          <Sidebar.Items>
            <Sidebar.ItemGroup>
              <Sidebar.Item href="#" icon={HiMailOpen}>
                Dashboard
              </Sidebar.Item>
              <Sidebar.Item href="#" icon={HiShoppingCart}>
                Sign
              </Sidebar.Item>
              <Sidebar.Item href="#" icon={HiPencilAlt}>
                Dash
              </Sidebar.Item>
              <Sidebar.Item href="#" icon={HiLink}>
                Board
              </Sidebar.Item>
              <Sidebar.Item href="#" icon={HiDatabase}>
                Login
              </Sidebar.Item>
              <Sidebar.Item href="#" icon={HiChartBar}>
                Search
              </Sidebar.Item>
            </Sidebar.ItemGroup>
          </Sidebar.Items>
        </Sidebar.Collapse>
      </Sidebar>
    </Flowbite>
  );
};

export default RightSidebar;

enter image description here
I tried to look in documentation but could not find anything in sidebar theme regarding tooltip

Could you provide a link to a sandbox environment where I can reproduce your issue? I don't see any tooltip when I'm trying to reproduce the issue.

you can use my code when sidebar is collapsed, the toggle button also show tooltip and I dont find reason to show tooltip on toggle button.
you can see in attached image that when I hover over toggle it shows tooltip, even though I removed text from tooltip it still shows that black part

I do not see any way to specifically target the Tooltip of the SidebarCollapse component using Flowbite's theming API. It might still be possible to achieve this with plain CSS.

yes its possible through plain css, but I want to find if there's another way
